# Unable to open a connection to Azure webapp, log stream is not loading in webapp

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-webapps

In webapp, Log stream is not loading, I'm getting error like "Unable to open a connection to your app. This may be due to any network security groups or IP restriction rules that you have placed on your app. To use log streaming, please make sure you are able to access your app directly from your current network"
Can some one help me out this..
[image]

Comment: How you have deployed your WebApp?What is the framework and version you are using?

Comment: Deployed via azure devops pipeline, Python flask project and version-3.8

Comment: Change the network connection to other and check once. Are you running the App in VNet?

Comment: I have deployed the app and able to see the [Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqB1l.png).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Initially when I opened `Log stream`, got the below alert.

[image]

- In `App Servive logs`, make sure `Applicaton logging` is set to `On`.

[image]

- Now Iam able to see the logs.

[image]

- Another option to check `Log Stream` is from KUDU Console.

[image]

***URL for KUDU LogStream*** - `https://YourAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/logstream`

[image]